# ERROR:iDEAL test bank: couldn't process your test payment

Tags: php, payment, magento

I integrated [mollie iDeal Payment](https://github.com/mollienl/magento) module in Magento 1.7.0. When I enable the test mode in the Mollie-account from  Magento admin config, I  see only the TBM Bank (testbank) as an option.

When I select this I see following error:

> iDEAL test bank: couldn't process your test payment: Aww man! I could not process the payment you tried to set up for testing. Usually, this means that you haven't enabled testmode for your account. This is required to use the testbank.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to log in into your Mollie account, and go to "Instellingen" below "Mijn betaaldiensten". There you can enable the testmode and use the iDEAL test bank.

If you upgrade to the latest Magento module, you will no longer need to perform this step but you can just switch your live and test API keys from you Magento admin.